# tidymodels recipe: Using all_of to select variables stored in a vector

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-recipes

I would like to use a vector with column names for a variety of step functions in the `tidymodels` recipe package. My intuition was simply to use (the `prep` and `juice` just used here for illustration):

```
library(tidymodels)
library(modeldata)
data(biomass)

remove_vector <- c("oxygen","nitrogen")

test_recipe <- recipe(HHV ~ .,data = biomass) %>%
  step_rm(remove_vector)

test_recipe %>% 
  prep %>% 
  juice %>% 
  head
```

But this returns the warning:

```
Note: Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous.
i Use `all_of(remove_vector)` instead of `remove_vector` to silence this message.
i See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html>.
This message is displayed once per session.
```

This, of course, concerns me (I want to make sure I code without coming across error messages), but I still get the outcome I desire.

However, when I follow the error message and use the following with `all_of`:

```
test_recipe <- recipe(HHV ~ .,data = biomass) %>%
  step_rm(all_of(remove_vector))

test_recipe %>% 
  prep %>% 
  juice %>% 
  head
```

I get the error message:

> Error: Not all functions are allowed in step function selectors (e.g. `all_of`). See ?selections.

In the `?selections`, I don't seem to find reference to the exact (seemingly simple) problem that I have.

Any ideas?
Many thanks!

Comment: This is not your fault because the error message is confusing, but recipes doesn't yet understand all tidyselect selectors. Looks like you [already found what is currently implemented](https://recipes.tidymodels.org/reference/selections.html), and we are working on making this cohesive. For sure this is not a great combination of error messages!

Comment: Great, thanks for confirming Julia! Keep up the good work on tidymodels, looking forward to what's coming soon! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use quasiquotation you won't get a warning:

```
library(tidymodels)
library(modeldata)
data(biomass)

remove_vector <- c("oxygen", "nitrogen")

test_recipe <- recipe(HHV ~ .,data = biomass) %>%
  step_rm(!!!syms(remove_vector))

test_recipe %>% 
  prep %>% 
  juice %>% 
  head
```

More on the warning. It can happen that you name vector the same as one of your column names. For example:

```
oxygen <- c("oxygen","nitrogen")

test_recipe <- recipe(HHV ~ .,data = biomass) %>%
  step_rm(oxygen)
```

This will remove only `oxygen` column. However, if you use `!!!syms(oxygen)`, both columns will be removed.

Comment: This works, thanks! Would you be able to comment why this would need three ```!!!``` - normally I would have guessed it would just be the simple ```!```.

Comment: I don't think you can use a single `!` for quasiquotation. It's `not` operator. You can use bang bang (`!!`) to unquote one argument and `!!!` for multiple arguments. More on that in [Hadley's book](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#unquoting).